# Find Redirect URL in Excel

Tags: vba, clickbank

I have around 10000 url all urls will redirect to another website. Is there any way to get the  website list in excel or any other application.

If its less than 500, i would have try macro code, but here number is huge. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the [RESTful API](http://longurl.org/api) provided by [LongURL.org](http://LongURL.org).

Comment: Thanks Yosi, can we use that in excel? i am not an expert in apis. i checked the link.

Comment: I am not very experienced with Excel macros, but the following info might help you: http://help.targetprocess.com/integration_api/excel